# Compact steel toaster ovens without glass?

Tags: equipment, oven, toaster

Are there any compact, counter-top, steel toaster ovens that do not have glass windows? The closest I've been able to find are Wisco's pizza ovens, but I would like something smaller (sandwich/pannini size). Is there a name for such ovens? (They use them at Taco Bell for making small quesadillas or toasting tacos.)

Comment: Why do you want something without glass?

Comment: A good question from @logophobe, the glass is extremely useful in a toaster oven as it helps you gauge when the food is done.